# Tabbar icons pixelated

Tags: ios, pixel, tabbar

Using this code

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];

    tabBarItem1.title = @"Home";
    tabBarItem2.title = @"Maps";
    tabBarItem3.title = @"My Plan";
    tabBarItem4.title = @"Settings";

    [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"]];
    [tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maps_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maps.png"]];
    [tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myplan_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myplan.png"]];
    [tabBarItem4 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"]];
```

is working fine..however, when I use this images, it looks pixelated on real iphone testing..using a larger (in width and height)images wont fit right because only portions of it are seen. is there a way that I can stretch these larger images to a specific width and height so the whole portions of it are seen?

Comment: Could you provide the dimensions of the .png files?

Comment: Its 30x30px.. I would like to use a larger one something around 90x90 so it wouldnt look pixelated

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html

Answer (score 2):

Follow the sizes outlined in the  [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html)
. Additionally, don't specify the .png since you want to be able to account for non-retina and retina images (w/ @2x).

Comment: what do u mean by dont specify the .png?

Comment: Just do [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourName"] instead of [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourName.png"]

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 or earlier, if you wanted to create a button with 32x32 size, You'd make a PNG with those pixel dimensions, and call it Button.png

Then when retina screens came along, you started to need to make 2 assets
Button.png AND Button@2x.png the @2x asset is 64x64 pixels.

With iOS7 and later, there's no need to make both assets. You just use the retina @2x assets.

Putting all your image assets into asset catalogs makes this much easier. So when you use the @2x asset from code you should not write the .png extension.

For example:

```
[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_selected"]...
```

Note: When you reference the asset @2x asset from Storyboard, you only write the name of the asset without the @2x.

For example: for your file called `home_selected@2x.png`, in `StoryBoard` you would write `home_selected.png`